# Droppable not accepting correct input if I use the .each method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please explain why the droppable is not accepting a correct value if I use the jQuery each method on the array.  It works fine if I use a normal JavaScript for loop with identical code.

So I don't understand, why it is not working with the jQuery each method?

fiddle  and code below.
http://jsfiddle.net/BuGA9/

```
$(function() {
var answer = ["apple", "tree"];
$("p.sen").draggable({revert: 'invalid'});
$("#dropBox").droppable({
    accept: function(element){
        $word = element.text().trim();


        for (var index in answer) {
           if($word === answer[index] || rem($word) === answer[index] )  { 
            return true;
            } 
        }
        /*

        $(answer).each(function(index) {
            if($word === answer[index] || rem($word) === answer[index] )  {
            return true;
            } 
        });  
        */

    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $( this )    
            .addClass("correct")
            .find( "p" )
                .html("Correct well done!!!!");   
   }
});
});

function rem(sentence) {
sentence = sentence.substring(0, sentence.length - 1);
return sentence;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return in the each returns the value from the iteration function, and not your accept function. You must create a variable outside the scope and set it in order to return it later.

```
var isCorrect = false;            
 $(answer).each(function(index) {
 if($word === answer[index] || rem($word) === answer[index] )  {
   isCorrect = true;
   return false;
 } 
});  
return isCorrect;
```

Also, I suggest you use native JavaScript loops when you can - the jQuery each is usually a bit slower.

http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the code example. And I was unaware of native JavaScript for loops being faster, so thanks for that tip also.

Answer (score 0):

as per [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

We can **break** the $.each() loop at a particular iteration 
by making the callback function **return false**. Returning **non-false** 
is the **same as a continue** statement in a for loop; it will 
skip immediately to the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation, your snippet did explain the reason why it was not working, thanks.